# Find the area of the region determined by the system

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, area

Find the area of the region determined by the system
\begin{align*}
y &\geq |x| \\
y &\leq -|x+1| + 4.
\end{align*}

I figured out that $x=-14$~$24$ and $y=-9.1$~$29.$  Can someone check my work and finish this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly how did you come to that conclusion? Did you plot it to see the region? How do you find the area of the region? See the region here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Cx%7C,+-%7Cx%2B1%7C+%2B+4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region is a quadrilateral whose sides are along the lines $y=x$, $y=-x$, $y=4-(x+1)=3-x$, and $y=4+(x+1)=5+x$. Looking at the the slopes of the lines it is easy to verify that this quadrilateral is actually a rectangle. By computing the mutual intersections we find the vertices:
$$A:=(0,0),\quad B:=(3/2,3/2), \quad C:=(-1,4), \quad D:=(-5/2,5/2).$$
The sides are $|AB|=3\sqrt{2}/2$ and $|AD|=5\sqrt{2}/2$.
Hence the area is $|AB|\cdot|AD|=15/2$.

Comment: @Moo Of course. Thanks.